# How to obtain/generate client.ovpn file?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I want to do a simple task: Connect to OpenVPN server to surf web. To do this, I found [this tutorial](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/182-how-to-connect-to-access-server-with-linux-clients.html) which consists in three basic steps:

- Install an OpenVPN client for Linux (done)
- Login to the Access Server's Client Web Server and download the desired client config file (typically called "client.ovpn"
- Run the OpenVPN client with the downloaded client config file

I created my account on this site openvpn.net but found nowhere to get this "client.ovpn" file. How do I get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An openvpn *.ovpn file is a configuration file which tells the client to which server it should connect. It can either be typed out manually, or it could be generated by the vpn server.

It seems you're confusing the openvpn site with an openvpn server.

The openvpn site provides information about openvpn. Openvpn is the vpn software which is used for the client and server. Openvpn is only the software, not a provider of a vpn service.

The openvpn server (or provider) can be any computer running the openvpn software, configured as an openvpn server. This can be a commercial service (free or paying), a raspberry pi with openvpn installed, a NAS, a router, a dedicated server or a home hosted server,...

If you're using openvpn from a provider on the web, the site of your provider should explain where to download their config file.

In short, they're explaining how to use the program, and in their "get the ovpn file" step, they're pointing you to any server/party whose vpn services you want to use

Openvpn advertises privatetunnel in their own app, but you can use any openvpn server of your choice.

Comment: Yes, thanks. This happened because I was thinking that OpenVpn site also offered a Server to connect, which is not the case.